# gcc/clang: How to force ordering of items on the stack?

Tags: gcc, clang, inline

Consider the following code:

```
int a;
int b;
```

Is there a way to force that a precedes b on the stack?

One way to do the ordering would be to put b in a function:

```
void foo() {
    int b;
}
...
int a;
foo();
```

However, that would generally work only if b isn't inlined.

Maybe there's a different way to do that? Putting an inline assembler between the two declarations may do a trick, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you ask? In principle,an inlined function call has the same semantics as the non-inlined call! What is the actual use case? Please **edit your question** to explain more.

Comment: After inlining, optimiser is free to mix local variables of callee and caller. I want to prevent that.

Comment: No, it won't mix variables. However, it could reuse a register, or a call frame slot, for another variable. Still, why don't you want that? By definition, function inlining is an optimization transparent to the semantics of your program, so you really need to motivate your question (and you might have an XY problem). And you should edit your question, not comment it.

Comment: I am using a variable length array to shift sp to a new stack (ugly, i know), however, for that to work reliably, i have to make sure that variables declared after the shift won't get laid out before the array. A non-inlined function call should do the trick, I suppose.

Comment: You probably should instead consider the `-fsplit-stack` option. It is dedicated for a usage very similar to your needs

Comment: My macro looks like this "go(foo(arg1, arg2, arg3))" and launches a new coroutine. I don't believe split-stack can be used to implement that.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: you can try -fno-inline-functions option, but this is for all functions

Comment: @Nick: This function call should not be inlined: https://github.com/sustrik/libmill/blob/master/libmill.h#L104

Comment: I downvoted the question, since most of it is in your comments. As I told, you (Martin Sustrik) should edit your question, not comment it.

Comment: I flagged the question, since it is still unclear and has changed completely. I hope it will get deleted.

Comment: @MartinSustrik - I can not understand why you want function not to be inlined, but I am not a pro. my solution function not to be inlined, would be to define it in different .o file. Then you can have 100 % chance function not to be inlined in compile time, since function is not there. However it might be inlined in linking time.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial question was about forcing a function call to not be inlined.

To improve on [Jordy Baylac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32341049/841108)'s answer, you might try to declare the function within the block calling it, and perhaps use a [statement expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

```
#define FOO_WITHOUT_INLINING(c,i) ({ \
  extern int foo (char, int) __attribute__((noinline)); \
  int r = foo(c,i); \
  r; })
```

<sup>(If the type of `foo` is unknown, you could use [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html))</sup>

However, I still think that your question is badly formulated (and is meaningless, if one avoid reading your comments which should really go inside the question, which should have mentioned your [libmill](https://github.com/sustrik/libmill)). By definition of [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion), a compiler can inline any function as it wants without changing the semantics of the program.

For example, a user of your library might legitimately compile it with `-flto -O2` (both at compiling and at linking stage). I don't know what would happen then.

I believe you might redesign your code, perhaps using `-fsplit-stack`; are you implementing some [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) in C? Then look inside the numerous existing implementations of it, and inside [Gabriel Kerneis CPC](http://gabriel.kerneis.info/software/cpc/).... See also [setcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setcontext.3.html) & [longjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html)

Perhaps you might need to use somewhere the `return_twice` (and/or `nothrow`) [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) of GCC, or some `_Pragma` like [GCC optimize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html)

---

Then you edited your question to change it completely (asking about order of variables on the call stack), still without mentioning *in the question* your [libmill](https://github.com/sustrik/libmill/blob/master/libmill.h#L104) and its `go` macro (as you should; comments are volatile so should not contain most of the question).

But the C compiler is not even supposed to have a call stack (an hypothetical C99 conforming compiler could do whole program optimization to avoid any call stack) in the compiled program. And GCC is certainly allowed to put some variables outside of the call stack (e.g. *only* in registers) and it is doing that. And some implementations ([IA64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) probably) have *two* call stacks.

So your changed question is completely meaniningless: a variable might not sit on the stack (e.g. only be in a register, or even disappear completely if the compiler can prove it is useless after some other optimizations), and the compiler is allowed to optimize and use the same call stack slot for two variables (and GCC is doing such an optimization quite often). So you cannot force any order on the call stack layout.

If you need to be sure that two local variables `a` & `b` have some well defined order on the call stack, make them into a `struct` e.g.

```
struct { int _a, _b; } _locals;
#define a _locals._a
#define b _locals._b
```

then, be sure to put the `&_locals` somewhere (e.g. in a `volatile` global or thread-local variable). Since some versions of GCC (IIRC 4.8 or 4.7) had some optimization passes to reorder the fields of non-escaping `struct`-s

BTW, you might customize GCC with your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to help about that (e.g. introduce your own builtin or pragma doing part of the work).

Apparently, you are inventing some new dialect of C (à la [CPC](http://gabriel.kerneis.info/software/cpc/)); then you should say that!

Comment: Hm. I can open a new question, something like "how to enforce ordering of items on the stack"... but changing this one would make all the answers/comments almost obsolete.

Comment: No, you need to **edit your question** to improve it. Comments may disappear with time. But your question would stay.

Comment: Mentioning `libmill`, giving an URL, explaining what your `go` macro is doing, and giving its source code should all go inside the question, not in comments!

Comment: Ok. I've rewritten the question.

Comment: But you did not mention `libmill` (with its github URL) or your `go` macro in it.

Answer (score 0):

below there is a way, using gcc attributes:

```
  char foo (char, int) __attribute__ ((noinline));
```

and, as i said,  you can try -fno-inline-functions option, but this is for all functions in the compilation process

Comment: Yes, I am aware of noinline attribute. What I've asked about though was whether it is possible to do that when *calling* rather than declaring a function.

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear for me why you want function not to be inline-d, but here is non-pro solution I am proposing:

You can make this function in separate object `something.o` file.

Since you will include header only, there will be no way for the compiler to inline the function.

However linker might decide to inline it later at linking time.